# Does Apache flink have any api as same as Spark HiveContext?

Tags: hive, apache-flink

I have read the document and reference about the Apache Flink 1.6 and want to find some api like Spark HiveContext to read data from Hive, but only find the HDFS api and JDBC api. Is there any api as same as Spark HiveContext to connect Hive ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HCatInputFormat](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/hcatalog/HCatInputFormat.html) like so:

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

env.createInput(new HCatInputFormat<>(database, table));
```

You probably need to add the dependency too:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-hcatalog</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

From Flink 1.9.0, we are officially supporting using Flink to read from and write to Hive. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/table/hive/

Are you still looking into this option? Feel free to reach out to me personally